# Appending in Serialization

Tags: java, serialization, netbeans, objectoutputstream

So far I have found that there is a way to do appending in serialization by making a sub-class but that seems like a lengthy way. Is there any better way to do appending in serialization?

I have this *vectorlist* in a class named *Course*

`private Vector<Student> StudentList = new Vector<>();`

I have 2 objects of *course*.
3 students are enrolled in 1 course and 2 students are enrolled in another. Now I call this method which is doing serialization in the file but when I call it with my 2nd course object, it replaces previous content.

```
public void Serialization() {
        try {
            File file = new File("EnrolledStudentsSerial.txt");
            if(!file.exists()){
               file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
            output.writeObject("Course: " + this.name + "\n\nEnrolled Students: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < StudentList.size(); i++) {
                Student p_obj = StudentList.elementAt(i);
                String content = "\n\tStudent Name: " + p_obj.getName() + "\n\tStudent Department: " + p_obj.getDepartment() + "\n\tStudent Age: " + p_obj.getAge() + "\n";
                output.writeObject(content);
            }
            output.writeObject("\n");
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Error: " + ioe.getMessage()); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append to a file, instead of replacing the content, you need to tell the [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) that, by adding an extra argument and call [`FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.io.File-boolean-). *FYI: don't do that with an `ObjectOutputStream`.*

You don't need to call [`createNewFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile--), since `FileOutputStream` will do that, whether appending or not.

However, you are not actually serializing your objects, since you're serializing strings instead. What you're doing makes no sense. Since you seem to want the result to be a text file (you're writing text, and file is names `.txt`), you should forget about [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html), and use a [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) instead.

Better yet, instead of using the old File I/O API, you should be using the "newer" NIO.2 API that was added in Java 7. You should also be using *try-with-resources*. Same goes for the ancient [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) class, which was replaced by [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) in Java 1.2.

Java naming convention is for field and method names to start with lowercase letter. And since your method is not "serializing" anymore, you should give it a better name.

Applying all that, your code should be:

```java
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.APPEND;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.WRITE;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

```java
private ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
```

```java
public void writeToFile() {
    Path file = Paths.get("EnrolledStudentsSerial.txt");
    try (BufferedWriter output = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, CREATE, APPEND, WRITE)) {
        output.write("Course: " + this.name + "\n\nEnrolled Students: ");
        for (Student student : studentList) {
            String content = "\n\tStudent Name: " + student.getName() +
                             "\n\tStudent Department: " + student.getDepartment() +
                             "\n\tStudent Age: " + student.getAge() + "\n";
            output.write(content);
        }
        output.write("\n");
    } catch (IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("Error: " + ioe.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I am actually pretty new to Java and I am doing this for my college assignment so I have understood how to append to a file but this code is gonna write a normal text right? So how do I serialize it?

Comment: @HarisMusa Why do you want to do Java serialization on *text*? It makes no sense.

Comment: So I have worked on my concepts and now I understand that the objects are supposed to be serialized but I still have 2 questions. *1.* How can I append 2 objects in the same file, like serialize 1 object then the other one. *2.* What is the benefit of serialization like I just tried serializing an object then deserializing it but what can I do with it after serializing? benefits and uses?

Comment: @HarisMusa 1) You should not append to a Java serialization file. 2) Are you asking for the purpose of serializing? Please do some *research* by looking on the web. That question has many answers out there.